# JavaScript event, not updating knockout observable/model value

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have text field which is wired up with Keyup & change event, to trim the field length.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.zipCode, new {data_bind = "textInput: zipcode, event: { keyup: trimField, change: trimField }", maxlength = "5"})
```

Trim function,

```
function trimField(data, event) {
    var obj = event.target;
    var maxlength = parseInt(obj.getAttribute('maxlength'), 10);
    obj.value = obj.value.substring(0, maxlength);
    obj.focus();
    return true;
}
```

If I type "123456", on the UI it shows "12345", but the model has "123456".

How to get model updated after the keyup event?

Comment: you listed maxlength as "5". Try changing it to "6"

Comment: I want my model to be "12345", not 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not updating the observable variable which is bound to your element. It is better to make it generic as an observable extend so it can be used everywhere based on your max-length and to make sure it follows your rule for an initial value.

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/55/

HTML:

```
 <input data-bind='textInput: zipCode' />
 <div>
   zip code in Model:<span data-bind="text:zipCode"></span>
 </div>
```

JS:

```
   function AppViewModel(input) {
    this.zipCode = ko.observable(input).extend({ maxLength:5});
    this.phone = ko.observable(input).extend({ maxLength:11});
   }



 ko.extenders.maxLenght = function(target, characters) {
     //you can use this to show an error message on view 
    // target.validationMessage = ko.observable();

    //define a function to do validation for maxLength
    function validate(newValue) {

    var maxlength = parseInt(characters, 10);
     if(newValue){
      target(newValue.substring(0, maxlength) ); 
     }

    }

    //initial validation
    validate(target());

    //validate whenever the value changes
    target.subscribe(validate);

    //return the original observable
    return target;
};

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel("12345678910"));
```

Comment: Looks interesting!! Thanks. Let me try this

Comment: trying to understand "target.validationMessage = ko.observable();" ?

Comment: That's a message variable which is bound to the target so in validate function you can set it with a message when validation is not passed and then in your view the message will show up whenever there is an error.Since you are forcing max length you can just remove that validation message.

Answer (score 0):

change maxlength from 5 to 6:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.zipCode, new {data_bind = "textInput: zipcode, event: { keyup: trimField, change: trimField }", maxlength = "6"})
```

Comment: I want my model to be "12345", not 6

Comment: but according to you, your model had a 6 digit one - "123456"

Comment: Yes, that is my issue now. I was able to update the control value to "12345" from "123456", but model got "123456" which suppose to be "12345"

Answer (score 0):

Stop modifying the DOM. That's Knockout's job. You just modify the data item and Knockout will ensure that the UI is right.

```
function trimField(data, event) {
    var obj = event.target;
    var maxlength = parseInt(obj.getAttribute('maxlength'), 10);
    data.zipcode(data.zipcode().substr(0, maxlength));
    return true;
}
```